# How to configure Raven for an Android project to have custom tags?

Tags: java, android, sentry, raven

I have managed to integrate *Raven* into my Android project by following the procedure provided in README file: [Raven-Android on GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven-android).

I can also build events myself with custom tags and successfully capture them using instance of Raven.

The problem is, that when a "real" exception is thrown (not generated by me on purpose of testing), for example `NullPointerException`, it gets reported to Sentry with default tags.

What should I do to make all the reported exceptions to have my custom tags?

Comment: This isn't currently supported, I've created a ticket and will try to get to is ASAP. https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/issues/293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although custom tags are not supported at the time of writing this, I managed to set them by providing custom implementation of `RavenFactory.java` and `EventBuilderHelper.java`.

[This pull request](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/pull/290) helped a lot.

The only thing that stays unsolved is that although I can add my custom tags, I cannot remove default tags.

Comment: What default tags are being sent that you'd like to remove? When I raise something like a `NullPointerException` I don't see any tags set.

Comment: `level`, `release`, `server_name` - I do not need those and they keep popping.